# Accessing NPM public vs private package source code in node_modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, node-modules, npm-install

I'm pretty new to javascript development so apologize in advance if this seems obvious. I'm trying to build a **private** npm package that is not accessible to users.

However, I am able to see other npm package code that's supposedly not open-source by going into their respective **node_modules** subdirectory. So I'm wondering what the difference is between public and private npm packages since one can view the source code via **node_modules** folder either way.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The privacy setting only affects wether a package can be published to a package registry or not and which people are able to access the package (e.g using restricted packages for custom company packages which are used in several projects). So *"private"* helps in preventing a package from being accidentally published and restricts the set of users who can access the package.

**This is not a way to somehow obfuscate or hide your code from people whom you shared the package with!**

While there are ways to achieve what you want to do, it's not as simple as you might think, as JS itself is not a compiled language and ca. (One way would be to write the code you want to hide in another, compiled language, e.g. C, and then call your C library via JS, basically using JS just as a wrapper)

TL;DR: If you grant users access to an NPM package they will be able to see the code of the package, end of the story. You can only decide who will be able to see/access the package by setting the privacy (public/private/restricted) of the package.